# geometric probability --- parallelograms

Tags: geometric-probability

Inside  a  rhombus   E  with  sides  10  unit   and  one  interior  angle  less  than  90  degree , there  are  2  parallel  (  with  E ) parallelograms  A  and  B  , both  can  move  freely  and  uniformly  inside  E  but  must  keep  parallel  with  E  in  moving . 
A  is  with  base   8  unit  and  adjacent  side   6  unit ; while  B  is with  base  5  unit  and  adjacent  side  9  unit . If  a  point  is  chosen  randomly  in  E  , find  the  probability  that  the  point  lies  inside  A  and  B  at  the  same  time .

Comment: make a picture?

Comment: @D Adams . It  is  difficult  for  me  to  do  so !

Comment: @mrwong: It's difficult for us to understand the question without one.

Comment: @joriki . Welcome to join the discussion of this type of problem in www.mathisfunforum.com if you are interested !

Comment: These parallelograms must have parallel all sides to the sides of the rhombus?    In this  case it is easy to imagine the situation .. just to have a blank sheet of paper and a pencil :)

Comment: @Widawensen : Yes , welcome  to  give  your  opinion !

Comment: @mrwong Unfortunately I'm not an expert in probability ( lately I'm only "expert" in rotation matrices :) but with great interest I would look at the solutions... as I've said they might have even a practical importance for some applications..

Comment: @mnwong I'm thinking still about your phrase "both can move freely and uniformly", I suppose you mean that probability that parallelogram is at the moment in its space of available positions is uniform, but interesting problem would be if really it could start from selected position and move in one direction and after touching opposite side move in other and so on. The second parallelogram  the same starting from the position at the other direction. Does the way of moving changing something here ? Probably so, because some areas would be meet more often than others.

Comment: @Widawensen : In  fact  the  word  " move"  is not  essential . It  is  just  used  to  describe  that  the  parallelograms  can  appear  at  any  possible  
positions  inside  the  rhombus with  equal  chance , but  the  parallelograms  and  the  rhombus  must  be  in  parallel  positions  with  fixed  corresponding  sides . You  are  right , the  2  parallelograms  will  meet  more  often  at  certain  positions  especially  at  the  centre  of  the  rhombus  , since  they  are  blocked  by  the  sides  of  the  rhombus .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that everything happens in the unit square $[0,1]^2$.

Begin with the following one-dimensional problem: We have a movable subinterval $J\subset[0,1]$ leaving free space of  length $0<\ell\leq{1\over2}$, whose position is uniformly distributed within the given limits. Denote by $p(x)$ the probability that the point $x\in[0,1]$ is covered by $J$. Then $p(1-x)=p(x)$, by symmetry. For $0\leq x\leq{1\over2}$ it is easy to see that
$$p(x)=\cases{{\displaystyle{x\over\mathstrut \ell}}\qquad&$(0\leq x\leq \ell)\>,$\cr 1&$\bigl(\ell\leq x\leq{1\over2}\bigr)\>.$\cr}$$
If we now have two such intervals $J_1$, $J_2$ such that $\ell_1<\ell_2\leq{1\over2}$, distributed independently, then the probability $q(x)$ that $x$ is covered by both intervals computes to
$$q(x)=\cases{{\displaystyle{x^2\over\mathstrut\ell_1\ell_2}}\qquad&$(0\leq x\leq \ell_1)\>,$\cr
{\displaystyle{\mathstrut x\over\mathstrut\ell_2}}\qquad&$(\ell_1\leq x\leq \ell_2)\>,$\cr 1&$\bigl(\ell_2\leq x\leq{1\over2}\bigr)\>.$\cr}$$
In the case at hand we have $\ell_1={1\over5}$, $\ell_2={1\over2}$ for the $x$-direction. If we now assume that $x$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ as well the overall probability $P_x$ that the random point $x$ is covered by both intervals becomes
$$P_x=2\int_0^{1/2}p(x)\>dx=2\int_0^{1/5}10x^2\>dx+2\int_{1/5}^{1/2}2x\>dx={71\over150}\ .$$
Similarly for the $y$-direction: Here $\ell_1={1\over10}$, $\ell_2={2\over5}$.  The overall probability $P_y$ that a random point $y$ is covered by both intervals becomes
$$P_y=2\int_0^{1/10}25x^2\>dx+2\int_{1/10}^{2/5}{5x\over2}\>dx+2\int_{2/5}^{1/2}1\>dx={71\over120}\ .$$
The probability $P$ that a uniformly distributed random point $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ is covered by both random rectangles at the same time is therefore given by
$$P=P_x\cdot P_y={5041\over18\,000}\doteq0.280056\ ,$$
as indicated by the OP in a comment (now deleted).

Comment: Thanks @Christian Blatter , Please  also  refer  to  my  another  question  " geometric  probability  ---rectangles " . I  believe  you  can  also  solve  it  in  a  similar  way .

Comment: There is a thread concerning this type of problem in www.mathisfunforum.com . Perhaps you will  be  interested !

Comment: You  may  be  interested  about  the  formula  I  used  
to  find  the  answer  of  this  question , it  can  be  
found  in  a  thread  in www.mathisfunforum.com .

Answer (score 1):

We can either impose oblique $(x,y)$ coordinates on the plane of the
three paralellograms, with the $x$- and $y$-axes parallel to the sides of
all the parallelograms,
or we can transform the plane linearly (preserving relative areas)
so that the rhombus becomes a square.
Either way, it is convenient to place the axes so that the bottom and
left sides of the rhombus lie along the $x$- and $y$-axes, respectively.

Taking the random variables 
$X_A,Y_A$ as the coordinates of the lower left corner of parallelogram $A$,
$X_B,Y_B$ as the coordinates of the lower left corner of parallelogram $B$,
and $X_P,Y_P$ as the coordinates of a random point $P$ within the rhombus,
let the variables have pairwise independent distributions
\begin{align}
X_A &\sim U(0,2) \\
Y_A &\sim U(0,4) \\
X_B &\sim U(0,5) \\
Y_B &\sim U(0,1) \\
X_P &\sim U(0,10) \\
Y_P &\sim U(0,10) \\
\end{align}
where $U(a,b)$ is the uniform distribution on the interval $[a,b]$.

Now, $P$ is (strictly) inside $A \cap B$ if and only if
$$\min\{X_A,X_B\} < X_P < \max\{X_A+8,X_B+5\}  \tag Q$$ and 
$$\min\{Y_A,Y_B\} < Y_P < \max\{Y_A+6,Y_B+1\}. \tag R$$
(If a point on the boundary of $A \cap B$ counts as "inside both $A$ and $B$"
then change $<$ to $\leq$ in the previous statement.)

Since the variables are pairwise independent, so are the events $Q$ and $R$
described by equations $(Q)$ and $(R)$, respectively, and the answer
to the question, $P(Q \cap R)$, obeys the equation
$$ P(Q \cap R) = P(Q)  P(R).$$
So consider equation $Q$. For given values $X_A = x_A$ and $X_B = x_B$,
let $u = \min\{X_A,X_B\}$ and $v = \max\{X_A+8,X_B+5\}$; then
$$P(Q \mid X_A = x_A, X_B = x_B) = P(u < X_P < v) = \frac{1}{10}(v - u)$$
(since $0 \leq u \leq v \leq 10$).
So the unconditional probability $P(Q)$ is just $frac{1}{10}$
of the mean size of the interval $[\min\{X_A,X_B\},\max\{X_A+8,X_B+5\}]$.
I figure the mean of $\max\{X_A+8,X_B+5\} - \min\{X_A,X_B\}$ is 
$\frac{71}{15}$, so $P(Q) = \frac{71}{150}$,
and by similar reasoning $P(R) = \frac{71}{120}$,
so I find that
$$ P(Q \cap R) = \left(\frac{71}{150}\right) \left(\frac{71}{120}\right) 
= 5041/18000 \approx 0.2800555\ldots.$$

Comment: Thanks @David K ,Please  also  refer  to  my  another  question  " geometric  probability  ---rectangles " . I  believe  you  can  also  solve  it  in  a  similar  way .

Comment: Both  your  answer  and  Christian  Blatter 's answer  are  correct , but  why  I  can  only  choose  one ?

Comment: There is a thread concerning this type of problem in www.mathisfunforum.com . Perhaps you will  be  interested !

Comment: You  may  be  interested  about  the  formula  I  used  
to  find  the  answer  of  this  question , it  can  be  
found  in  a  thread  in www.mathisfunforum.com .